# Is there a way to get the ID of a Google Drive folder from the path using Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Let's say I have a folder on GDrive with the path `/content/drive/MyDrive/MyFolder`. I know I can access the contents of the folder from Google Colab after mounting Drive. But is it also possible to access the ID/URL of this folder using Colab, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `kora` to get ID from a file path.

```py
!pip install kora
from kora.xattr import get_id
fid = get_id('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks')
# 0B0l6No313QAhRGVwY0FtQ3l1ckk
```

Comment: Thanks to this, I don't need to manually enter the ids of hundreds of google drive folders